# How can I give feedback on Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, feedback

How can I give feedback on Eclipse?

Here's what I've tried:

`Eclipse -> Help ->  Report Bug or Enhancement...` takes me to a `Bug` window that gives me a `Anonymous can not submit Tasks!` error when I try to submit it. I have to spend extra time explaining that I'm not submitting a bug, but an enhancement, or rather a piece of feedback. I feel there must be something more effortless and painless than this method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you click the "Anonymous can not submit..." link, it will bring up a dialog to configure your connection to Eclipse bugzilla system. Since you obviously don't have an account there, use the "Create new account" link in that dialog to create an account (it dumps you to the web site to do that).

Eclipse Bugzilla is for entering bug reports or feature/enhancement requests. If what you want to say is neither of those, try posting on the [Eclipse Community Forums](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/). Also, if you would prefer to file a bug or enhancement via the standard web interface, you can access it [here](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/). It's generally a good idea to search for similar reports before posting a new one. It's also not a bad idea to discuss the topic on the forums before creating a bugzilla report.

Comment: @ERiz, thank you. I basically knew of (most of) these methods, but thought there might be a quick shortcut I was missing.